# TimePicker - Time is not selected properly

Tags: javafx, gluon

When i try to select a time (3:15 as example) on the display it is mostly one minute beside the actual desired time. Mostly - sometimes it is selecting properly but i didn't find out when. Is it a known bug? Do i have to set a range or something. Thanks for any help.

[image: TimePicker]

Comment: What method do you use to display time?

Comment: TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker();timePicker.showAndWait().ifPresent(System.out::println);